# Excel: Insert formulas in a dynamic range

Tags: excel

**The context:**

Depending on the size of a few input columns, I'd like to have a column with formulas that adjust to the size of those inputcolumns. I know how to do this with VBA, but I would really like to know if there's another way to do this.

**The details:**

This is a basic setup where columns A and B are values, and column C consists of a simple formula where specifically range C2 has the formula `=A2+B2`. Now i can make the columns A and B dynamic ranges by using `Formulas > Name Manager` and inserting the formulas `rng_A=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2;;;COUNTA(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$40);)` and `rng_B=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$2;;;COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$40);)` like this:

[image]

This comes in handy for charts where you can use the named ranges for a dynamic display of the data like this:

[image]

Now, If I insert two new numbers in column A, the chart would automatically add them to the line:

[image]

**The question**:

If I'd like to add column C in the chart, that could be done just as easily by adding a new named range, but I would have to insert two new formulas in range C8 and C9. Is it in any way possible to make column C a dynamic range that consists of formulas? **Without** filling the entire column with formulas such as `=IF(A8="";"";A8+B8)` here:

[image]

**Or** using a VBA snippet?

Than you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c) (select your range and then **Insert > Table**) and make C a calculated column.

[image]

This way, when you add more rows to the table, the formula applies to column C in that row.

Answer (score 1):

Consider just using an event procedure like this one.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Rng As Range

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
        Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1))
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            With Target
                Set Rng = Range(Cells(.Row, "A"), Cells(.Row, "C"))
            End With
            With Rng
                .Cells(3).Value = .Cells(1).Value + .Cells(2).Value
            End With
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Whenever you make a change to either A or B the total is made in column C. The formula could be tweaked to write zero, or blank out the cell, if only column B has a value.

Answer (score 1):

In the sheet code, using the change event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column = 2 Then
Range("C" & Target.Row).Formula = "=A" & Target.Row & "+B" & Target.Row
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Tables are a great way to accomplish this, I won't knock it.  If instead you specifically want a formulaic approach without either VBA or named ranges, then you have `FILTER()`.

A simplistic approach:

```
FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")
```

However, your input data has a header, so you have to filter that out too:

```
FILTER(A:A,(A:A<>"")*(A:A<>A1))
```

The asterisk here acts as a Boolean AND. Each of the sub-tests returns an array of TRUE/FALSE a million entries long (the max size of a column) but you can let Excel deal with that nuance.  The multiplication converts TRUE/FALSE into 1/0.  1*1=1, everything else =0, so it essentially results in an array of a million 1/0 result that define the criteria of which cells in your input column (also a million entries) pass through the filter.

So C2 then becomes:

```
=FILTER(A:A,(A:A<>"")*(A:A<>A1))+FILTER(B:B,(B:B<>"")*(B:B<>B1))
```

If you want to handle the potential that you have only A or B populated but not both, you can wrap that in an `IFERROR` function.  Or allow the `#N/A` error to exist; up to you.  I'm sure there's a way to curtail the spilled array at C2# so that it's only as long as the shorter of A or B, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.